# Running Upgrade via command

Tags: command-line

I was trying to run upgrade in ubuntu having run update via command but,afterwards, it displayed:

```
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

please, what does that msg mean?

Answer (score 0):

> ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent
>   shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command
>   line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories
>   (/lib and /usr/lib). The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so
>   or ld-linux.so. ldconfig checks the header and filenames of the
>   libraries it encounters when determining which versions should have
>   their links updated.

Please check ldconfig manual `man ldconfig`